# How to put multiple form_for's on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Oke guys i'm busy making an invoice app and i'm kinda stuck atm.

On the invoice page i have something similar like

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
 <%= f.date_select :date %>

    <%= form_for :customer do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :company_name %>
    <% end %>

 <%= f.text_field :invoice_number %>
<% end %>
```

But when i save the invoice and try to edit it again the customer details are gone.

**How do you put multiple form_for's in one page and save them all with one submit button?**

Comment: outer form will submited all the time better to use ajax on click of inner form

Comment: put an answer together demonstrating how that might work and I'll definitely vote for it :)

Comment: i'll upvote the answer if you put it together. :) one way would be to create a new route where you `POST` the form, and then handle the models individually, but it won't be a `form_for`.

Comment: try using fields_for inside the form and save it.

Comment: <%= fields_for :customer, @invoice.customer do |c| %> isn't working. I get; SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: customers.invoice_id

Comment: there isn't a way to submit multiple forms at once. Maybe combine them into a single form. You could get it done with Javascript, but you'll have to convert all the form submissions to AJAX (i.e. making a `submit` event on the parent form and submitting the others using `$.get(url, data)` and making a success callback).

Comment: Yeah i thought something like that. Could you perhaps give an answer to demonstrate how to do that? I think these guys above are curious aswell.